# Converting Complex to ArrayList<Float> in Java

Tags: java

I have an input signal that I want to store in an ArrayList then convert it into Complex, which goes something like this

```
-0.03480425839330703
0.07910192950176387
0.7233322451735928
0.1659819820667019
```

and this outputs its FFT like this

```
0.9336118983487516
-0.7581365035668999 + 0.08688005256493803i
0.44344407521182005
-0.7581365035668999 - 0.08688005256493803i
```

This is in a complex structure, I want to convert this into an ArrayList type. while dropping the `+ 0.08688005256493803i` value.

So All I need are these values

```
0.9336118983487516
-0.7581365035668999
0.44344407521182005
-0.7581365035668999
```

What is the best way of going about this?

And this is the code that I am using

```
public static Complex[] fft(Complex[] x) {
        int N = x.length;

        // base case
        if (N == 1) return new Complex[] { x[0] };

        // radix 2 Cooley-Tukey FFT
        if (N % 2 != 0) { throw new RuntimeException("N is not a power of 2"); }

        // fft of even terms
        Complex[] even = new Complex[N/2];
        for (int k = 0; k < N/2; k++) {
            even[k] = x[2*k];
        }
        Complex[] q = fft(even);

        // fft of odd terms
        Complex[] odd  = even;  // reuse the array
        for (int k = 0; k < N/2; k++) {
            odd[k] = x[2*k + 1];
        }
        Complex[] r = fft(odd);

        // combine
        Complex[] y = new Complex[N];
        for (int k = 0; k < N/2; k++) {
            double kth = -2 * k * Math.PI / N;
            Complex wk = new Complex(Math.cos(kth), Math.sin(kth));
            y[k]       = q[k].plus(wk.times(r[k]));
            y[k + N/2] = q[k].minus(wk.times(r[k]));
        }
        return y;
    }
```

Comment: Show us code for `Complex` data type

Comment: @mishadoff I uploaded the code as well

Comment: I asked about `Complex` class not fft method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want to do is just drop imaginary part of your `Complex` data structure.

As you not show us `Complex` class assume it has member for real part (e.g `double real;`)
To drop imaginary part just call something like `complex.getRealPart()`, or access `complex.real` (substitute with your real member name).

To compose `ArrayList<Double>` use the following snippet:

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (Complex c : complexes) {  // complexes your array of complexes returned from for fft
  list.add(c.getRealpart());
}
```

**Note:** Just in case, I can be wrong, but I assume that instead of real part you need absolute value of complex number. To calculate it use:

```
Math.sqrt(c.getRealPart() * c.getRealPart() + c.getImPart() * c.getImPart());
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you just want the real part of the complex value. If that's the case, presumably your Complex class also has getReal() and getImaginary() (or similar) methods - so just use getReal().